# Pull data into a list from one sheet to another and keep that list data static after it is pulled in Microsoft Excel Sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I am not sure if this is possible but I want to create a sheet that is able to pull the data from another sheet and put it into a static list. We have a team sheet with all current projects. Once the projects are completed they are taken off the list. I was hoping I could create sheet (say sheet 2) of a compiled list of all data inputted into sheet 1 and then sheet 2 is a static list, even if sheet 1 is updated or something is changed sheet 2 keeps that original information, and new data inputted into sheet 1 is just added onto the list on sheet 2. Is this possible and if so how?

I am currently trying to read up on if this is possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To better help you solve your problem. If possible, could you describe your problem in more detail?